# Expected view Client_view to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

```
[Error][1]
AssertionError at /api/client-details/ Expected view Client_view to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly. Request Method: DELETE Request URL: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/client-details/ Django Version: 2.2.6 Python Executable: C:\Users\AravindManoj\PycharmProjects\Client\venv\Scripts\python.exe Python Version: 3.7.4 Python Path: 
['C:\\Users\\AravindManoj\\PycharmProjects\\Client\\Client',
'C:\\Users\\AravindManoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
```

While using Generic view in Django it Showing Error while using DELETE function.Please anyone give me the syntax of generic views in model set i didnt find any problem but no Delete function

Views.py

```py
    from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
    from rest_framework import viewsets, status, generics
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from .serializers import ClassSerializer
    from .models import Client

    class Client_view(viewsets.ModelViewSet, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        queryset = Client.objects.all().order_by('-Name')
        serializer_class = ClassSerializer*
        lookup_fields = ['Name', 'UserName', 'Mobile', 'Email', 'Address']
```

urls.py

```
    from rest_framework import routers
    from .views import Client_view
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register('', Client_view)
    urlpatterns = router.urls
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    class Client(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        UserName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        Email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        Address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

serializer.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Client
    class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Client
            fields = ['Name', 'UserName', 'Email', 'Mobile', 'Address']
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are trying to accomplish with this view?

Answer (score 1):

When using a `ViewSet` (in your case you are using a `ModelViewSet`) the view requires a `pk` value from urls. This is done automatically when using a router.

The router will create a number of urls:
Example:

```
router.register(r'', Client_view)

URL pattern: ^$ Name: 'client_view-list'
URL pattern: ^{pk}/$ Name: 'client_view-detail'
```

One of the attributes of a ViewSet is `lookup_field`, the lookup field allows you to change the name of the url capture you are using. In your case, you seem to have `lookup_fields` and specified multiple values. Try changing this to `lookup_field='pk`.

As a side note, it can be helpful to take a look at the restframework source code around [Views](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/generics.py#L24).

Answer (score 1):

You have used `lookup_fields` which is not any built-in feature. Try to do it with a custom mixin like described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

just add lookup_field = 'pk' on the Client_view...

ie:

```
class Client_view(viewsets.ModelViewSet, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        queryset = Client.objects.all().order_by('-Name')
        serializer_class = ClassSerializer*
        lookup_field = 'pk'
```